# Setting constants in a function containing If

Tags: function-construction

I'd like to set the constants in a function that uses If, after it's been defined, but my definitions doesn't seem to stick.  Simple example:

```
f[x_] := If[x < 1, f1, f2]
f[x]
(* If[x < 1, f1, f2] *)

{f1, f2} = {-1, 1};
f[x]
(* If[x < 1, f1, f2] *)
```

Instead of the last one, I want to get

```
If[x < 1, -1, 1]
```

Any ideas how? I have a feeling this should be easy but it's hard to search for.

Comment: Why not define `f` to have `f1` and `f2` as its parameters at the outset? `f[f1_, f2_, x_] := (* stuff *)`

Comment: You have to give x a value when you call f, otherwise the truth of the test in If cannot be determined and Mathematica returns it as it got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If` has attribute `HoldRest`:

```
Attributes[If]
(* {HoldRest, Protected} *)
```

and so the second and third arguments are not evaluated unless `If` chooses to do so, which, unless the first argument evaluates to `True` or `False`, it does not.

You can use `With` to insert the defined values of `f1` and `f2` prior to evaluation:

```
Clear[f, f1, f2];

f[x_] := With[{f1 = f1, f2 = f2}, If[x < 1, f1, f2]]
f[x]
(* If[x < 1, f1, f2] *)

{f1, f2} = {-1, 1};
f[x]
(* If[x < 1, -1, 1] *)
```

The odd-looking syntax in the first argument of `With` works because only the right-hand sides of the assignments are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have guessed that!

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround (inspired by Simon Rochester's observation about If's HoldRest attribute) -- make a "new" If without that attribute:

```
If2[a_, b_, c_] := If[a, b, c];

f[x_] := If2[x < 1, f1, f2]
f[x]
(*If[x<1,f1,f2]*)

{f1, f2} = {-1, 1};
f[x]
(*If[x<1,-1,1]*)
```

(seems safer than changing the real If!)